# Application defined or object-defined error when opening a second workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code where I open 1st workbook, then open the 2nd workbook, copy a range from the 1st workbook and paste it in the 2nd workbook.

```
 Sub test()
        '**VARIABLES**
        Dim folderPath As String
        folderPath = "Y:\plan_graphs\final\mich_alco_test\files\"
        Dim fileTitle As String
        fileTitle = "5.xlsx"

        Dim dataWorkbook As Workbook
        Set dataWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(folderPath & fileTitle)

        'Dim resultWorkbook As Workbook
        'Set resultWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open("Y:\plan_graphs\final\mich_alco_test\result.xlsx")

        Dim copyRange As Range
        Set copyRange = dataWorkbook.Worksheets("List1").Range("A3:F3", Range("A3").End(xlDown))

        copyRange.Copy
        'resultWorkbook.Worksheets("1").Range("A3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas


End Sub
```

But I get the `Application defined or object-defined error` error on line

```
Set copyRange = dataWorkbook.Worksheets("List").Range("A3:F3", Range("A3").End(xlDown))
```

When I comment the lines related to the second workbook, no error happens. Why does this error happen?

**EDIT**: The interesting thing is, that if I define and set the `copyRange` **before** opening the 2nd workbook, it works fine... I'm really curious of what about opening the 2nd file messes the `copyRange` and why opening that file later helps.

Comment: @Mrig The error is still there...

Answer (score 2):

It depends which workbook you have active when you run the code.
This line of code potentially looks at two different workbooks:
`Set copyRange = dataWorkbook.Worksheets("List").Range("A3:F3", Range("A3").End(xlDown))`.

`dataWorkbook.Worksheets("List").Range("A3:F3"` - this always looks at the `List` sheet in the `dataWorkbook`.

`Range("A3").End(xlDown)` - this always looks at the currently activesheet which is in `resultWorkBook` when those lines aren't commented out.

Use:
`Set copyRange = dataWorkbook.Worksheets("List").Range("A3:F3", dataWorkbook.Worksheets("List").Range("A3").End(xlDown))`

or

```
With dataWorkbook.Worksheets("List")
    Set copyRange = .Range("A3:F3", .Range("A3").End(xlDown))
End With
```

Comment: Thanks. But why though it would result in an error? So even if looks at `resultWorkbook` and takes it's `Range`, what's so wrong with it to throw an error?

Comment: It's because you're telling it to create a range from two different sheets across two different workbooks.  The range `A1:F3` must be on the same sheet - you're telling it to start at `A1` on the `List` sheet and end at `F3` on whichever sheet is active.

Comment: You may also want to change the code that finds the last cell.  If A4 downwards is empty `copyRange` will refer to `$A$3:$F$1048576`.  If you use `.Range("A3:F3", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))` then it will refer to `$A$1:$F$3` and you can check if the first row is less than 3 then there's no valid data.

Comment: Thanks I might consider this, but for now it looks like all my files have no empty cells in A column - in valid range.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
Option Explicit

 Sub TestMe()

    Dim folderPath      As String
    Dim dataWorkbook    As Workbook
    Dim resultWorkbook  As Workbook
    Dim copyRange       As Range

    folderPath = "C:\Users\USER_CHANGE\Desktop\"
    Set dataWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "5.xlsx")
    Set resultWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "6.xlsx")

    dataWorkbook.Activate
    Set copyRange = dataWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A3:F3", Range("A3").End(xlDown))

    copyRange.Copy
    resultWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas

    dataWorkbook.Close True
    resultWorkbook.Close True

End Sub
```

I have changed a bit the folderPath and I have added a `dataWorkbook.Activate`, for the copying and pasting. There are other ways around, to avoid the activation, but it works. At the end, I close both workbooks and I save the changes.

Furthermore, `Worksheets` are refered by index.

Comment: I added `dataWorkbook.Activate` but it still fails(

Comment: Your code worked. Now I'm completely confused. Thank you for your answer though, but it's very very weird.

Comment: I have a more complicated code that first opens a `resultWorkbook` outside the loop, then opens one of the files in a folder, copies-pastes the range to `resultWorkbook`, saves `resultWorkbook`, loops to the next file. So the `resultWorkbook` never closes there is always opened before the file, and `dataWorkbook.Activate` doesn't help there.

Comment: @Ans - start debugging line by line of your code and check is happening. Try to simplify it, it should work.